# CIFS FSTAB won't start at boot and mount -a doesn't work as expected

Tags: boot, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am having a odd issues my CIFS drive. It won't mount at boot and also when the system has booted, I have tried again with mount -a but no success. It will however mount with the mount -t command and when I unmount this share that does not exist(see code below). It seems that Ubuntu is tracking that it's mounted when df and the actually folder are reporting something different.

This is on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server

I will say that this seem to begin when I added a bridge interface to this server for KVM so I am not sure if that has caused this.

```
john@Main-KVM:~$ sudo mount -a -vvv
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: UUID=4449ee44-4389-4aa0-b47b-6ef85b43b7da already mounted on /boot
mount: UUID=FEFA-B2F0 already mounted on /boot/efi
mount: //192.168.0.10/Public/public already mounted on /home/john/UN_RAID
nothing was mounted




john@Main-KVM:~$ df
Filesystem                     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Main--KVM--vg-root 222912116 116356924  95208864  55% /
none                                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                             8192876         4   8192872   1% /dev
tmpfs                            1641356      1156   1640200   1% /run
none                                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                             8206772         4   8206768   1% /run/shm
none                              102400         0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda2                         241965     97760    131713  43% /boot
/dev/sda1                         523248      3468    519780   1% /boot/efi
/home/john/.Private            222912116 116356924  95208864  55% /home/john




john@Main-KVM:~$ sudo umount /home/john/UN_RAID
umount: /home/john/UN_RAID: not mounted





john@Main-KVM:~$ sudo mount -a -vvv
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: UUID=4449ee44-4389-4aa0-b47b-6ef85b43b7da already mounted on /boot
mount: UUID=FEFA-B2F0 already mounted on /boot/efi
mount: spec:  "//192.168.0.10/Public/public"
mount: node:  "/home/john/UN_RAID"
mount: types: "cifs"
mount: opts:  "guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.cifs"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "//192.168.0.10/Public/public"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/home/john/UN_RAID"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,guest,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777"
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.10,unc=\\192.168.0.10\Public,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user=,prefixpath=public,pass=********
nothing was mounted



john@Main-KVM:~$ df
Filesystem                      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Main--KVM--vg-root  222912116  116356924   95208864  55% /
none                                    4          0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                              8192876          4    8192872   1% /dev
tmpfs                             1641356       1156    1640200   1% /run
none                                 5120          0       5120   0% /run/lock
none                              8206772          4    8206768   1% /run/shm
none                               102400          0     102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda2                          241965      97760     131713  43% /boot
/dev/sda1                          523248       3468     519780   1% /boot/efi
/home/john/.Private             222912116  116356924   95208864  55% /home/john
//192.168.0.10/Public/public   9523094052 5631232832 3891861220  60% /home/john/UN_RAID
```

Here is how it currently appears in my fstab file.

```
//192.168.0.10/Public/public /home/john/UN_RAID cifs guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: Hi edward, thanks for look at my issue here but I do not think they are related since this is for ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have updated this to reflect that.

Comment: What's the type of the device  /home/john mount? Is it already mounted before you run "mount -a" the first time?