# NAS won't mount at boot but will mount with mount command after boot

Tags: boot, mount, samba, fstab

https://askubuntu.com/questions/640118/nas-wont-auto-mount-at-boot - no answers

[CIFS FSTAB won't start at boot and mount -a doesn't work as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684343/cifs-fstab-wont-start-at-boot-and-mount-a-doesnt-work-as-expected) - not related, `sudo mount -a` works for me

[CIFS mount through fstab not mounting at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399643/cifs-mount-through-fstab-not-mounting-at-boot) - 2 answers, neither one works

My fstab entries are like:

`//192.168.1.9/music /media/music cifs credentials=/home/media/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0`

None mount at boot.

I don't get any errors or anything when I use `sudo mount -a`. Wired CAT5 connection. `192.168.1.9` is a Synology NAS. is it possible that I need to put some sort of wait in here? I added _netdev for that reason when I was on a wireless connection...

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

Comment: Try using //192.168.1.9/music /media/music cifs username=the_username,password=the_password 0 0 then run mount -a to see if it works. Also make sure you have cifs-utils installed.

Comment: If it works then something is wrong with .smbcredentials

Comment: but why would it mount with `mount -a` if the smbcredentials was goofed up?

Comment: The only reason to use smbcredentials is so you don't have to put credentials in fstab. Look closely at my first comment.

Comment: Having the same problem. mount -a works, but SMB/CIFS share fails to mount at boot.   I've read _netdev doesn't work anymore, but haven't seen a working replacement, nor specific documentation that netdev doesn't work anymore. Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/787363/19193 states that netdev doesn't work for NFSv4 (still worked for NFSv3 and nothing about CIFS).